# Error while using next/image with MDX content - `validateDOMNesting`

Tags: next.js, styled-components, mdxjs

I'm creating a Next.js blog using `mdx-bundler` and `styled-components`. I'm using [`remark-mdx-images`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark-mdx-images) to import images into JSX. I created a custom component (`styled.div`) to embed the `next/image` in it.

But when I run the blog in browser, i'm receiving an error saying that `validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.` I tried switching this to `styled.span`, but its doesn't display the image at all even though its rendered in DOM

I'm also receiving another warning: `Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <p>.`

Below is the code that I have

```js
import Image from 'next/image';

const CustomImage = styled.div` // cannot change this to styled.span
    position: relative;
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;

    & .image{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: unset !important;
    min-height: unset !important;
    min-width: unset !important;
    }

`

const MDXImage = (props) => {

    return (
        <CustomImage>
            <Image className='image' src={props.src} alt={props.alt} layout="fill" objectFit="contain" />
        </CustomImage>
    )
}
```

below is the complete error:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
    at div
    at O (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:31:19811)
    at MDXImage (webpack-internal:///./pages/blog/[slug].js:52:19)
    at p
    at p
    at main
    at div
    at Post (webpack-internal:///./pages/blog/[slug].js:138:19)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:24:24)
    at StyleRegistry (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/stylesheet-registry.js:231:34)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ErrorBoundary.js:26:47)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:90:23)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:265:5)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:769:24)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:914:26)
```

Comment: [leerob suggests](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19733#discussioncomment-148287) using the `<Image />` directly within the MDX files or using `remark-unwrap-images`